# python anonymous class variables names

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python anonymous class . I found this code online

```
class Struct(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        d = self.__dict__
        results = [type(self).__name__ + "("]  # or: self.__class__.__name__
        for key in sorted(d.keys()):
            if (len(results) > 1): results.append(", ")
            results.append(key + "=" + repr(d[key]))
        results.append(")")
        return "".join(results)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(repr(self)) # inefficient but simple
```

The usage is

```
obj = Struct(x=1, y=2, c=3)
obj.x #1
obj.y #2
```

I wonder how can I dynamic assign variable names.

I am trying to do something like this

```
for i, item in enumerate(row):
    object = Struct()
    a = (header[i])
    object.a= item
```

Obviously this is wrong, `a` in `object.a` is string `a`. How can I dynamically do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) function, to create a attribute. Quoting the documentation,

> The arguments are an object, a string and an arbitrary value. **The string may name an existing attribute or a new attribute.** The function assigns the value to the attribute, provided the object allows it. For example, `setattr(x, 'foobar', 123)` is equivalent to `x.foobar = 123`.

So, in your case, you can create an attribute with the value from `header[i]`, like this

```
setattr(obj, header[i], item)
```

Comment: Thanks, I also just find it form documentation.